# Show Bootstrap modal on page load after scrolled percentage only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have this almost working but seem to be missing some logic. I want the bootstrap modal to appear when someone gets 70% down the page when scrolling. It works, but when I close the modal it opens right back up again since I am still at 70% on the page. Any idea how to only make the modal open once after I close it?

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
  var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
  var documentHeight = $(document).height();
  var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

  if(scrollPercent > 70) {
      // Popup in view after 70% scroll
     firePopup();
  }

  function firePopup() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

  function reposition() {
      var modal = $(this),
      dialog = modal.find('.modal-dialog');
      modal.css('display', 'block');
      dialog.css("margin-top", Math.max(0, ($(window).height() - dialog.height()) / 2));
  }
  $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', reposition);
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $('.modal:visible').each(reposition);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I meant any idea how to only make the modal open once and not again after I close it?not Any idea how to only make the modal open once after I close it?

Comment: intercepting the close event and to kill all classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a class to modal once it is displayed and if class exists then dont show it again.

```
function firePopup() {
  if(!$('#myModal').hasClass('displayedOnce')){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#myModal').addClass('displayedOnce');
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a global variable `modalOpened` and set it to `false`, and set it `true` when modal opened. Then you could check `modalOpened` and only show modal if it's `false`. Something like this.

```js
var modalOpened = false;
$(document).scroll(function(e){
  var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
  var documentHeight = $(document).height();
  var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;
  if(scrollPercent > 70) {
      // Popup in view after 70% scroll
   if(!modalOpened){
    firePopup();  
   }
  }

  function firePopup() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
 modalOpened = true;  
  }

  function reposition() {
      var modal = $(this),
      dialog = modal.find('.modal-dialog');
      modal.css('display', 'block');
      dialog.css("margin-top", Math.max(0, ($(window).height() - dialog.height()) / 2));
  }
  $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', reposition);
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $('.modal:visible').each(reposition);
  });
});
```

```css
.app{
 background: gold;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bootstrap Modal</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="app"></div>
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias illo doloremque voluptate numquam corporis exercitationem, nemo voluptatibus fuga magni labore voluptas et porro necessitatibus nulla accusantium omnis vitae perspiciatis. Maiores veniam excepturi praesentium cum aliquid ratione tempora blanditiis repudiandae dolorum distinctio quo ad facere, est similique. Distinctio odit debitis quae aliquid commodi aperiam, asperiores aut, adipisci sunt quod cum placeat nemo facere iusto, laudantium earum quis quasi atque rerum. Dolorem porro reprehenderit, repellendus obcaecati a sapiente deserunt eligendi, reiciendis incidunt atque officiis animi aliquam esse cumque rerum debitis dignissimos veritatis, non ullam earum hic maiores neque magni at! Sapiente nostrum debitis atque repellat porro earum ipsum et, nobis iure, autem amet tempore doloremque dignissimos, asperiores ullam quo aliquid repellendus ea obcaecati eos voluptatem deleniti optio! Architecto cum a dolor aliquam nam ex illo ipsum dolorem expedita, fugiat! Non, dolores totam aliquam fugiat et nobis. Ab illo, pariatur adipisci mollitia cum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil pariatur quas commodi aspernatur sequi minus adipisci quam eveniet labore aut molestiae dolores corporis numquam, dolore consequuntur unde laudantium sed illo facere rerum tenetur, fuga! Error nam ipsa, facilis enim porro at! Non, officiis, omnis. Sed quia quam, deleniti nostrum officia consectetur. Quam nemo incidunt magnam ut aspernatur obcaecati non tenetur quidem inventore, asperiores quaerat. Saepe amet temporibus, reiciendis deserunt, repellendus eum accusantium iure. Incidunt enim nisi quae rerum maiores iste reiciendis, voluptates culpa in maxime numquam tenetur rem, tempora cumque expedita praesentium eum dolor! Rerum nemo magni doloribus, voluptatem quisquam impedit tempora, repudiandae architecto perspiciatis quo at aliquid dolor voluptate voluptates, numquam recusandae quasi asperiores soluta deserunt adipisci eius provident quidem odio. Sit aperiam impedit voluptatem ipsum incidunt consequatur pariatur, similique natus enim, officiis officia dolor voluptatum! Rerum reiciendis, illo commodi ea corporis distinctio necessitatibus quidem! Quidem qui autem, consequuntur tempora praesentium saepe officia ipsam harum iure doloribus cumque culpa ipsa, ad accusamus aliquid pariatur animi! Animi accusantium id, ad consequuntur illo, porro similique quisquam, fugit harum dolore quasi facilis impedit tenetur quibusdam placeat et doloribus excepturi perspiciatis hic labore ex doloremque? Nam, voluptas, aspernatur. Quia temporibus odit, reiciendis fugit.</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, this will not persist once browser reloaded, if you want to display it once every day or week or something like this, you have to use cookies or localStorage.